# static linking to .dylib in xcode 4.5 error

Tags: dll, xcode4, static-libraries

I'm trying to use FMOD, I'm recreating one of the example projects. When the program loads, it says

```
  dyld: Library not loaded: ./libfmodex.dylib
  Referenced from:     (...project filepath...)
  Reason: image not found
```

I'm linking by going to build phases of the target, expanding link with binaries, clicking the + sign, clicking other, then navigating to the libfmodex.dylib. It then automatically fills out the library search path.

The program builds and runs but stops instantly with the above error message. Is there some kind of compiler flag that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out elsewhere that it needs a build script added (target->build phases->add build phase->run script)

```
cp "/absolute/filepath/of/your/libfmodex.dylib" .
cp -f "$TARGET_BUILD_DIR/$PRODUCT_NAME" .
cp "/absolute/filepath/of/your/libfmodex.dylib" "$TARGET_BUILD_DIR"
```